# QtCreator: run application on remote device

Tags: qt, qt-creator, remote-debugging

I am used to develop Qt application for Raspberry Pi. On my development machine I run QtCreator and create a "Generic Linux Device" selected for the current kit.

In the pro file I specify the `target.path` in order to copy the files to the target.

When I launch the application, it runs *on the target*. I mean, if there's is a window it appears on the target's monitor.

Now I want to do the same using a standard desktop PC as target. Both dev and target machines run Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop.

But when I run the application, QtCreator tries to run it "locally" through the SSH connection. I'm not interested in the X11 forwarding. As said above I just want it runs the application on the remote device.

Is there anything I'm missing?

### UPDATE

Here the exact output when I try to run the application from QtCreator (expected to run on the target). Please note that 192.168.1.26 is the dev machine.

```
21:06:39: Checking available ports...
21:06:39: Found 101 free ports.
21:06:39: Starting gdbserver --multi :10000...
21:06:39: Debugging /home/user/bin/Flow -qmljsdebugger=port:10001,block,services:DebugMessages,QmlDebugger,V8Debugger,QmlInspector,DebugTranslation -qmljsdebugger=port:10001,block,services:DebugMessages,QmlDebugger,V8Debugger,QmlInspector,DebugTranslation ...
Listening on port 10000
Remote debugging from host 192.168.1.26, port 56914
Process /home/user/bin/Flow created; pid = 15917
Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
Could not load shared library symbols for 48 libraries, e.g. /home/user/Qt/6.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt6Gui.so.6.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vkkhrdisplay, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
```

Running the same binary file from the target itself leads to the correct behavior.

Comment: Maybe you need `gdbserver`. Try here http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/GDB/gdb_17.html

Comment: @IlianZapryanov on the target I have `gdbserver` installed. Is there something I need to configure on QtCreator? When I work on RPi it works out of the box

Comment: Ok, check the forum that is discussed here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/122540/qt-qpa-xcb-could-not-connect-to-display-error/6

Comment: @IlianZapryanov, apparently I solved the `DISPLAY` issue exporting `:0` instead of `0:0` as suggested. All the other warnings are still there but al least the application runs...